# PHP - C++ - real time port communication

Tags: php, c++, angularjs, serial-port, real-time

So, I try to make a little application in PHP which communicates with COM port on a local machine.

To do that, I use a C++ exe. I'm on windows environnement and reading COM port isn't possible in PHP because of timeout reading bug.

My application works fine. I can send via PHP a word, which is transmited to C++ exe and so on the COM port. This port respond me another word that it transmit by C++ to PHP. And if I want to display it, I have to wait the end of http call, so the COM port will be closed.

All that is fine. What I want to do, is open the COM port and listen it with PHP until the user decide to stop it. I simulate the COM port behavior with DockLight, so I can send words when I want.

**But how could I display the words send in real time, not just by calling the read function all the time ?** What's the right way to do that ?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've found a different solution.

I gave up the idea to pass with C++. I use [SerialPort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport/%22SerialPort%22) for COM port communication and [Socket.io](http://socket.io/%22Socket.io%22) for real time. No need to use php either.

It's a really good solution for my problem, and very simple to perform.